# Pass a function to a component arrived as '' Props ''. - React - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
  <SimpleDialog
            selectedValue={selectedValue}
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            title={title}
            componentBody={componentBody}
            />
```

I would like to pass the '' handleclose '' to the component (componentBody), but that component comes to me as '' props '', is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. All those values are passed and received as props, what's the concrete problem?

Comment: to component body, I pass a component that already comes to me as props in the modal, componetBody = {componentBody (I am the component arrived as props} in that component there is a button, to which I would like to pass handleclose on click. I don't know if I made myself clear !

Comment: I think so. In that case, you should could pass it at the upper level (where it's passed on originally), or else it must expose some method to allow you to set that handler. As it is now, it seems that you can only "pass as it comes" without interacting with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a `component` to another `component` you should use `high order components` or `HOC`, and wrap children components like layouts, like below:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <HOC message={"from App"}>
        <ComponentB name='Reza' func={() => alert("alert message")} />
      </HOC>
    </div>
  );
}
const ComponentB = ({ name, func }) => {
  return <h1 onClick={func}>name is : {name}</h1>;
};

const HOC = ({ children, message }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {message}
      <br />
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In your codebase you can do it like below:

```
<SimpleDialog
            selectedValue={selectedValue}
            open={open}
            title={title}
>
  <componentBody onClose={handleClose}/>
</SimpleDialog>
```